# How to split string into up to 2000 characters each at end of line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, match

Below is a small sample of a string variable named results ...

```
2017-09-18  920.0100  922.0800  910.5999  915.0000  1294800
2017-09-15  924.6599  926.4899  916.3599  920.2899  2505400
2017-09-14  931.2500  932.7700  924.0000  925.1099  1397600
2017-09-13  930.6599  937.2500  929.8599  935.0900  1102600
2017-09-12  932.5900  933.4799  923.8610  932.0700  1134400
2017-09-11  934.2500  938.3800  926.9199  929.0800  1267000
2017-09-08  936.4899  936.9899  924.8800  926.5000  995100
2017-09-07  931.7299  936.4099  923.6199  935.9500  1212700
```

How can I split it into an array with each part containing as close to 2000 characters as possible and ending at the end of a line. Been using following but that ends each item in the array in the middle of the line.

```
var parts = results.match(/[\s\S]{1,2000}/g);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you get up to 2000 chars in each match, you may use

```
var parts = results.match(/[\s\S]{1,2000}$/gm);
```

**Details**

- `[\s\S]{1,2000}` - 1 to 2000 any chars, as many as possible,
- `$` - end of line
- `/gm`  - enable multiple occurrence matching (`g`) and forcing `$` to match end of line (`m`).

Comment: Thanks, works fine, what is the main difference between your code vs what ctwheels posted?

Comment: No `\v` (it is not supported by the JS regex engine). Also, I explained why `m`  is important - it makes `$` anchor match the end of a *line*, rather than the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/w8j2rW/1)

```
[\s\S]{1,200}(?:\v|$)
```

### Explanation

- Match any character between 1 and 200 times
- Match a vertical whitespace character `\v` or the end of the string/file `$`

Obviously, in your case, you would use 2000 instead of 200.

Comment: If I change flavor to Javascript in your link, which is what I am using, it does not split at end of line.

Comment: Are you using `m` flag?